# HTML input name and how to output it

Tags: html

So I made `<input type="text" name="username">` and now after I type that text/name how do I make it appear on screen same like I logged in, it need to say the input.

Comment: Not really getting your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: I made a input username tag, and now I want that tag to show itself on the other page, like "Welcome, "username". Understand now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I got from your question is that you want to access the value from the input field

```
document.getElementById("name").value
```

Refer to this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p43drgwc/
You can find how to access the field value in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you will get the answer using **getElementsByName**

```
document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
```

getElementsByName will give you all the elements which have name as "username" in an array.

[0] represents the position  the with an array.